# Angular 5 ParamMap not working on app.component.ts

Tags: angular, parameters

I want to get id from route params but it return null as value.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {    
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(){  
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('idC');
    console.log(id);
}
```

routing.ts:

```
{ path: 'profile/:idC', component: AccountComponent }
```

The aim of code on app.component is because I'm using navbar on app so when a user is connected, the expected result is to get id from route so that navbar will display "Welcome user1". Any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to the `route.paramMap` observable to listen for changes?

Comment: Could you give me an example of the subscribe ?

Comment: @KrishnaRathore has already done so in his answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick `idC` from your `AccountComponent` and assign the value to a property inside service.

**account.component.ts**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, myService: MyService) { }

ngOnInit(){  
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('idC');
  this.myService.id = id;
  console.log(id);
}
```

Access the same service from your `AppComponent` and use that variable inside your HTML.

For example, inside your **app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, myService: MyService) { }
```

and your **app.component.html**

```
<p>ID: {{myService.id}}</p>
```

Comment: What to put on myservice ?

Comment: @Atom - It is a service which you can use to communicate between components. It could be an empty service, maybe called `shared-data.service.ts`. Inject the same service in both the components and use it the way it is used in the HTML above.

Comment: Yes I know, but how to assign id value from AccountComponent to service ? Could you please give me a sample of myservice. Thank you

Comment: @Atom  -Create a service, maybe an empty one using command `ng g service my-service`. Then write the code mentioned for `account.component.ts` above in the answer inside your `account.component.ts`. Then inject the same service inside your `app.component.ts` and access it in the HTML as mentioned above.

Comment: I did exactly what you've said. Thanks a lot, it worked!

Comment: Just one question, what if I want to assign myservice.id to a variable in app.component, I tried it and it returns undefined!

Comment: @Atom - Assign `myService` to some object in your component and use that object to point to the ID. It has a reason behind it. Objects are referenced by address. Hence, any changes inside an object itself will reflect in every place where it is referred. However, trying to access `id` directly wont reflect the changes because it becomes a primitive type.

Comment: Didn't get much from comment, you're saying I have to set a variable as an object in myService and assign it from component? A sample of code maybe could help.

Comment: @Atom Check pass by value and pass by reference. Maybe this article would help - https://hackernoon.com/grasp-by-value-and-by-reference-in-javascript-7ed75efa1293

Answer (score 4):

You can also get **params** value without **service**

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {

 this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
    let r = this.route;
    while (r.firstChild) {
        r = r.firstChild
    }
    r.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params.idC);
    });
  });

}
```